# Angular, ui-router: show loading when change state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Is there a way in angular that when I want switch to another state (ui-sref) that i can show some load icon until the second state is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes angular ui.router has events which you can listen:

`$stateChangeStart`  -   fired when the transition **begins**.

`$stateChangeSuccess` - fired once the state transition is **complete**.

following this you can write preloader functionality

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   $rootScope.preloader = false;
}

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       $rootScope.preloader = true;
    }
```

and write some   `<div>`  in your body element and show/hide it with this variable

eg.

```
<body> 
    <div ng-show="preloader"></div>
</body>
```